# iPhone/Objective-C - transform voice "live"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, voice

so i'm doing a little bit of research/thinking about a project i might do and have run into some questions you guys might be able to help me answer.

is it possible in an iphone app (objective-c) to apply effects to a mic-input live. i've seen quite a few applications in appstore allowing you to record a snippet and then apply various tranforms/sound effects to this. but is it possible to do this without the recording part - so i just can 'speak' and have the voice transformed instantly?

would appreciate any comments and/or pointers!

thanks!

roger

Comment: you'd have to turn up the volume!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer anything about the how or give any pointers, but it's definitely possible.

Check out the "I Am T-Pain" app from Smule.  It automatically plays the end results through headphones as you speak/sing, as well as giving you the options to save.